What is Mekor Mayim Chayim on Baal Shem Tov?
i.e. מקור מים חיים על בעל שם טוב, such as here on Sefaria - no useful info in the description, or online as far as I can tell. Does anyone have access to a physical copy of a Baal Shem Tov with Mekor Mayim Chayim or otherwise know who wrote this, when, and any other useful information on the work?

Mekor Mayim Chayim is the name of the commentary provided by the editors of the anthology Sefer Ba'al Shem Tov al haTorah on the material that they collected. The editors names were Rabbi Natan Nata Dunner and Rabbi Shim'on Menahem Mendel Wodnik, and they worked on the book between 1902 and 1916 (though it was only published in 1938). This information is from Menachem Kallus's introduction to his translation of a part of the book (Pillar of Prayer, 2011).
